# Running Totals of Commuter in Bus per stop at specified time using TSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem i needed to solve using sql server 2008. Below are the tables:

CommuterTrip_Details Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommuterTrip_Details](
[TripID] [int] NOT NULL,
[TripStartStation] [varchar](20) NULL,
[TripStartTime] [time](7) NULL,
[TripEndStation] [varchar](20) NULL,
[TripEndTime] [time](7) NULL)
```

BusTrip_Times Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusTrip_Times](
[BusID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StationID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DepartTripTime] [time](7) NULL)
```

**Below is the content of CommuterTrip_Details Table:**

```
+------+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
|TripID|TripStartStation| TripStartTime    | TripEndStation| TripEndTime      |
+------+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| 1    | Station_01     | 07:00:00.0000000 | Station_03    | 07:15:00.0000000 |
| 2    | Station_01     | 07:01:00.0000000 | Station_05    | 07:17:00.0000000 |
| 4    | Station_02     | 07:12:00.0000000 | Station_08    | 07:23:00.0000000 |
| 5    | Station_02     | 07:15:00.0000000 | Station_10    | 07:30:00.0000000 |
| 7    | Station_03     | 07:20:00.0000000 | Station_10    | 07:48:00.0000000 |
| 8    | Station_04     | 07:22:00.0000000 | Station_06    | 07:51:00.0000000 |
| 9    | Station_05     | 07:31:00.0000000 | Station_09    | 07:53:00.0000000 |
| 10   | Station_06     | 07:35:00.0000000 | Station_10    | 08:02:00.0000000 |
+------+----------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

**Below is the content of BusTrip_Times Table:**

```
+-------+------------+------------------+
| BusID | StationID  |  DepartTripTime  |
+-------+------------+------------------+
|     1 | Station_01 | 07:00:00.0000000 |
|     2 | Station_01 | 07:05:00.0000000 |
|     3 | Station_01 | 07:10:00.0000000 |
|     8 | Station_02 | 07:15:00.0000000 |
|    14 | Station_03 | 07:25:00.0000000 |
|    17 | Station_04 | 07:25:00.0000000 |
|    18 | Station_05 | 07:30:00.0000000 |
|    19 | Station_05 | 07:35:00.0000000 |
|    21 | Station_06 | 07:40:00.0000000 |
+-------+------------+------------------+
```

Desired Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfe1Z.png)

Explanation:

1. BusID = 1, boarded 1 commuter in Station_01 then commuter alighted in Station_03. Same is true with BusID = 2.
2. BusID = 8, boarded 2 commuters in station_02, up till station_08, where 1 commuter alighted, and 1 remained till station_10

Rest of the bus has the same concept.

To count the boarded commuters, TripStartStation = StationID and TripStartTime <= DepartTripTime.

The TripStartTime must get the closest DepartTripTime. I manage to get this using ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION.

Comment: I have tried working in C#, since it has more flexibility and an array of tools to use, what i have tried implementing are loops within datatables to do the comparison of station & time. And be able to come up with running totals bet station. My challenge is the speed. I was thinking that it could be faster within SQL Server running on server, hence the query. Was looking on this site for running totals but was not close to the problem, like using CTE.

Comment: Where do we see that 3 boarded at Station2? Could you post the schemas of these tables? It's hard to figure out the relationships from these pictures. You seem to be using an ID column differently in each table as a artificial key.

Comment: @AshleyPillay, the IDs in each table do not relate from each other, in BusTrip_Details, the ID is assumed as the commuter ID. While the ID in BusTrip_Times is like the bus ID. So basically, the two tables can only be related by the stations & time of trip. Added the schema of both tables.

Comment: There's still plenty of gaps in what you're trying to do here. If you can post the DDL for the tables, sample data, & the SQL you have tried so far, it'll be much faster for someone here to figure out what you're doing & help you.

Comment: @AshleyPillay, i updated the query with relevant details.